# Edit HTML with javascript: Insert \n instead of <br> as a new line

Tags: javascript, dom, wysiwyg

I am using this code to insert a new line in a content editable HTML document:

```
execCommand("insertHTML", false, '\n');
```

This works for me in Chrome and Safari, but it results in < br> or a new paragraph in other browsers. Because I am editing < pre> tags, I do not want the browser to change \n to a < br>. How can I do this?

I have already tried to use functions like range.insertNode() or to manipulate insertBrOnReturn in FireFox, but it is always the same. Isn't there a way to insert a \n in the document without the browser changing my input?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no cross-browser working way to add a `\n`... I am not THAT familiar with contenteditable but since it is changing the innerHTML you could maybe do something like

```
var currentContent = myContent; // "currentContent holds" the current content
execCommand("insertHTML", false, '\n'); // inserts the line break
if (newContent !== currentContent + '\n') { // "newContent" holds the content afterwards
  console.log('use String.prototype.replace to replace created tag with "\n"');
}
```

Comment: I have also thought about a browser switch to handle the browsers in different ways, that is not the problem. But a console.log will not solve the problem.

Comment: it should just give you an idea how to check whether the browser supports the `\n` insertion... if not you should replace the content... it seemed that you are familiar with string editing so I did not directly mentioned it but just give you a starting point to avoid or work around the problem

Comment: Okay, but I now the browsers. Safari and Chrome are working - FireFox, IE and Opera not, so I do not need a check for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to save the edited content afterwards, so how about replacing all `<br>`s with `\n`s when getting the content of the tag? Just like this:

```
document.getElementById("editable").innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
```

---

edit: You may also just use the innerText instead of the innerHTML. When doing so, all newlines are presented as `<br>` tags (at least I got that result in Chrome). This solution isn't great, but it's at least always the same.

Comment: I have also thought about this solution, but it is not working for me. The source code should be clean during editing without wrong tags in it, because the user can edit the document with an editor as well as in HTML mode and some users are confused about that. Isn't there a way to carry out something like "insertPLainText" instead of "insertHTML"?

Comment: @your edit: that is not the problem. I would like to have a simple \n instead of a br, for a br you can simply use execCommand("insertHTML", false, '<br>') and this is working in all browsers I have tested.